# Multiple level of routing using Express.js with Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express

I'm new to javascript. I'm trying to make a RESTfull API using Node.js and Express.js

My directory structure is as follows

> /server.js
>
> /api/api.js
>
> /api/location/location.js

I want to make the API modular. I want that all the requests (get/post/delete/push) beginning with `/api/*` to be handled by **api.js** and whatever routing be required, **api.js** should route it to proper module.

For example, if someone requests `GET /api/location/abc/xyz` then `api.js` will transfer control to `location.js` which will then transfer to `abc.js` which will finally transfer to `xyz.js` stored in **directory** `/api/location/abc/xyz/xyz.js`

How can I achieve this?

#### Code so far:

#### /server.js

```
var express  = require('express');
var app      = express();

var api      = require('./api/api.js');
var location = require('./api/location/location.js');

//app.use('/api/location', location); //This works, but I want api.js to handle sub-routes!

app.use('/api', api);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.end('successful get/');
});

app.listen(12345);
```

#### /api/api.js

```
module.exports = function(req, res, next) {
    res.end('successful get /api');
    next();
};

//Add code to handle GET /api/location
```

#### /api/location/location.js

```
module.exports = function(req, res, next){
    res.end('from location!');
    next();
}
```

Comment: Check out `express.Router()`.

Comment: I did, but couldn't figure out the logic to do it!

Answer (score 1):

You would use [`express.Router([options])`](http://expressjs.com/de/api.html#express.router).

And write it that way:

**/api/api.js**

```
var router = require('express').Router();

router.get('/location', require('./api/location') );

module.exports = router;
```

**/api/api/location.js**

```
module.exports = function(req, res, next){
   res.end('from location!');
}
```

And don't call `next();` if you ended the response. You only call `next()` in your callback if you don't handle the response.

I don't know how complex your REST api will be later. But try to to keep the routing in a small number of file. Having a callback for the routing in an own file like `/api/api/location.js` is most likely not the best idea.